# Why can read -q not be used inside double brackets in zsh?

Tags: if-statement, zsh

I have the following in my `.zshrc`:

```
#    if read -q; then
#        echo; zplug install
#    fi
     [[ read -q; ]] && echo; zplug install
```

The bit that is commented out worked, but I would prefer something on one line, so I attempted to use a less verbose form.  Why does it not work?

I get `/Users/brandon/.zshrc:62: parse error: condition expected: read`.

Comment: Note that adding commands like `read -q` that rely on a terminal being present to `.zshrc` is a bad idea. Make this also conditional on `[[ -t 0 ]]`

Comment: As the error message tells you, what you have inside your brackets is not a syntactically valid condition. In theory you could do something like `[[ $(read ....) == something ]]`, which indeed would execute a _read_ command, but this is pointless. I don't understand from your question what your code is supposed to achieve.

Comment: @user1934428 it is within a larger piece of code that checks whether new zplug plugins are listed in the zshrc and asks if you want to install them.  In the end I changed it to always install them, but the same change dealt with here was useful for the outer 'if' statement.

Comment: Then ask for input, and after this test for the content of the input.  Of course you **could** do this in a single command, such as `[[ $( (read x; echo $x) ) == Y ]]` to ask, whether the user entered `Y`, but I don't think this makes your program more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[[` is specifically for evaluating expressions, *not* return codes. The one-line equivalent for your `if` variant is<sup>(a)</sup>:

```
 read -q && { echo; zplug install }
```

If your `if` variant was something like:

```
if [[ something-or-other ]] ; then
    blah
fi
```

*then* you would use `[[` in your one-liner:

```
[[ something-or-other ]] && blah
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Note here the use of the braces to group the commands. The command `read -q && echo; zplug install` will run `zplug` unconditionally - only the `echo` will be subject to the `read` return value.